# the multi part identifier a@gmail.com could not bound

Tags: asp.net

The email column is at no 4 in the table
And the data type is varchar
con.Open();

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInfo where EMail=" + EMail + "", con);
    SqlDataReader dr;

    dr =cmd.ExecuteReader();//here I get error
    while (dr.Read())
    {

        lblCustName.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        lblAddress.Text = dr[2].ToString();
        lblMobNo.Text = dr[3].ToString();

        lblEMail.Text = dr[4].ToString();
        //con.Close;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass parameter bounded by single qoutes

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInfo where EMail='" + EMail + "', con);
```

Without single qoutes , the resuktant query is coming out to be

```
select * from UserInfo where EMail=a@gmail.com
```

where value **a@gmail.com** is being treated as **tableName.columnName** giving the error multipart identifier could not be bound.

Its better if you use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection attacks rather than passing values directly to query.

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserInfo where EMail=@Email", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email",SqlDbType.Varchar,1000).Value = Email;
```